# compare Value of cookie returns "false" every time

Tags: javascript, cookies, string-comparison, if-case

I got a function named `getCookie(x)` which returns the value of the cookie with name `x`.
When i check with `console.log(getCookie(foo));` it returns the correct term of either `solved` or an empty string if the cookies doesnt exist. `Foo` is a variable!

For this test, my cookie `foo` exists and the value is `"solved"`
but if I do this:

```
console.log(getCookie(foo) == "solved");
```

it returns false. Why is this?

this is my `getCookie()` Function:

```
function getCookie(cname){                                                                      
                var name = cname + "=";                                                         
                var carray = document.cookie.split(";");                                        
                for(var j=0; j <carray.length; j++){                                            
                        var cookie = carray[j];                                                 
                        while(cookie.charAt(0)==" "){                                           
                            cookie = cookie.substring(1);                                       
                        }
                        if (cookie.indexOf(name) == 0){                                         
                            return cookie.substring(name.length,cookie.length); //retruns the value of the cookie, in my case it is always "solved"
                        }
                }
                return "";  //if there is no cookie with the given name, it returns an empty string                                                                 
}
```

I deleted comments because they are not in english. My cookies also got an expire date, this is why I have to do these "wild" things to get the `cookiename=value` part.

Comment: is `foo` a variable or you meaned to write `"foo"`?

Comment: I tested your code on stackoverflow.com: `getCookie('_ga')` works. So i can not replicate the problem.

Comment: i checked my cookie variable with typeof and it returned "object". thats why it returned false when I gave an object to my getCookie function!

Answer (score 1):

i checked `console.log(typeof(foo));`
and somehow it was an Object, thats why my string comparion returned "false".